# How to resize the child component to the parent size that can be resized?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm displaying a list of items retrieved from the database.
Each item have an image URL and a boolean weather it is premium or not.

---

I want it if it is premium to display a **Box** above the actual image that is clickable for the user to watch an ad to be able to see the image.

I am loading the image using coil, so my problem is when the item is premium and the image is still loading the **Box** is composed but with the current size, and after the image is loaded the **Box** doesn't resize

This results in the **Box** not filling the available space as expected (see attached image)

This is my **ImageItem** composable fun:

```kotlin
 @Composable
    private fun ImageItem(
        wallpaperItem: Wallpaper
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            // Getting the image using coil
            SubcomposeAsyncImage(
                model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
                    .data(wallpaperItem.imageUrl)
                    .crossfade(true)
                    .build(),
                loading = { LinearProgressIndicator() },
                onLoading = { viewModel.isLoading(true) },
                onSuccess = {
                    viewModel.isLoading(false)

                },
                onError = { viewModel.sendUiEvent(UiEvent.ShowSnackbar(it.result.throwable.message.toString())) },
                contentDescription = null,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .clickable { viewModel.onEvent(HomeEvent.OnWallpaperClick(wallpaperItem)) }
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(12.dp))
            )
            // Checking weather the image is premium or not
            if (wallpaperItem.isPremium) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .alpha(0.5f)
                        .background(colorResource(id = R.color.darkGreen))
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = "Watch ad\nTo view the wallpaper",
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The result

[image: The result]

Expected

[image: Expected]

When the images is being loaded

[image: Images being loaded]

I've explored various solutions like using weight and onSizeChanged modifiers, but unfortunately, haven't found a successful solution. I'm relatively new to Compose and would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions you might have to address this issue.

Thank you for your time and support!

Comment: Are you displaying the `ImageItem` Composable in a `LazyRow` or `LazyColumn`? You can try to add the `matchParentSize()` Modifier to the Watch Ad Box instead of `fillMaxSize`.

Comment: That was so easy!! `matchParentSize()` fixed it. Thanks! :)

Comment: Glad to hear it worked! I added a formal answer, please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ImageItem` Composable probably is placed in a `LazyColumn`. As a result,  when you set nested Composables to `fillMaxSize`, this Modifier will be ignored.

What then happens is that the parent Box wraps the `SubcomposeAsyncImage` height. Once the height changes, the child Box size is not updated.

Please have a look at the [`matchParentSize`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/BoxScope#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).matchParentSize()) Modifier.

> Size the element to match the size of the Box after all other content elements have been measured.

This Modifier also works inside a `LazyColumn`. 
 You can adjust your code as follows:

```
if (wallpaperItem.isPremium) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .matchParentSize()
            .alpha(0.5f)
            .background(colorResource(id = R.color.darkGreen))
    ) {
        // ...
    }
}
```